# Android - making ExpandableListView elements have transparent backgrounds

Tags: android, user-interface, background, expandablelistview

I have an expandable list view I am using in one xml file which has a background. Upon loading, it looks fine, but sometimes while browsing the background of each list element shows infront of the background of the base view.

The list elements are defined in their own xml file.

Can I make the list elements backgrounds become transparent somehow, so that the background of the baseview is shown all the time instead, even when expanding/collapsing the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found here :)

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html

Use

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

On your list

Answer (score 1):

Set this all four properties for expandablelistview. It worked for me....

```
android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Or programmatically set expandablelistview transperent:

```
ExpListview SecondLevelexplv = new ExpListview(mContext);

SecondLevelexplv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
SecondLevelexplv.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
SecondLevelexplv.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
SecondLevelexplv.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);
```